# Асинхронный сайт — плохо ли?

Tags: javascript, html, seo, асинхронность

Пишу сайт. Полностью асинхронный. URL меняется динамически. При открытии страницы, берется URL, и в соответствии с этим берутся данные из БД. А пока достаются данные из БД, пользователю показывается анимация загрузки.

Вопрос: Будет ли подобный сайт парситься поисковиками? Если да, — то как (?!). Ведь теоретически, это не возможно. У роботов нет поддержки JavaScript. Или я чего-то не понимаю??

Каковы другие минусы асинхронности? (Исключая выключенный JS и старые браузеры)

Comment: Хорошо сделанный «асинхронный сайт» способен работать и без js (посмотрите, например, гитхаб или мобильную версию ВК)

Comment: `У роботов нет поддержки JavaScript` - это смотря у каких роботов

Comment: у поисковых есть поддержка `JS`?

Comment: Не у всех поисковиков есть поддежрка JS. У Google, например, есть. Я бы порекомендовал для таких сайтов менять meta tags на бэк энде.

Comment: простите, что значит `менять meta tags на бэк энде`?

Comment: Это значит, раз сайт полностью на js значит он работает используя post, get запросы, следовательно к нему прилетают какие либо данные, и вот именно с этих прилетевших данных, менять значения meta тегов под нужные страницы. И конечно же генерировать их в back-end.

Comment: По моему опыту - индексируются, но дольше, чем статические. Минусы - главный в быстродействии. Ведь каждый запрос требует времени. Для большого потока запросов это не кошерно... Второй минус - возможность информационного подчинения (если понимаете, о чем речь). Да и простые уязвимости будут проще - через запрос (ГЕТ) если он активен можно передавать много чего лишнего...

Comment: Ознакомьтесь: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174993?hl=ru&ref_topic=6003039 А вообще конечно всё это бред.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такие сайты, и есть общепринятый термин "SPA", значит, с точки зрения рынка это не может быть совсем плохо.

> Будет ли подобный сайт парситься поисковиками? Если да, — то как (?!).
>   Ведь теоретически, это не возможно. У роботов нет поддержки
>   JavaScript. Или я чего-то не понимаю??

Честно говоря, судя по вопросу, легче назвать что вы понимаете.
Уже давно существуют браузеры с открытым исходным кодом, и даже готовые headless-браузеры, поэтому современный поисковой бот теоретически должен создаваться именно на основе браузера, а не простого HTTP-клиента, тем более у Google, которые сами являются создателями одного из браузеров и им "сам Бог велел", а вот у Яндекс и таких, как Mail.Ru и Рамблер, дела хуже, но для них просто делается "статическая" версия.

> Каковы другие минусы асинхронности?

А сами вы их не видите, разработка дольше и дороже, это главное.

Comment: «разработка дольше и дороже» — не обязательно, воткнуть pjax или что-то подобное — дело нескольких минут

Comment: @andreymal Но с PJAX теряется то преимущество, что полноценное API, естественно, возвращающее JSON, может еще и стать back-end для приложений Android, iOS и т.п. Кроме того, PJAX предназначен только для частичной перезагрузки страницы, а чтобы асинхронно отправить POST-запрос, все равно нужно API.

Comment: Ну если делать API для мобильников, то тут уже неважно спа или не спа - время всё равно потратить придётся, а для всего остального API необязательно)

Comment: @andreymal Бред. Если вы пишете приложение без AJAX, то у вас вообще нет никакого API и его придется делать отдельно, если же SPA, то можно сразу сделать API, годное и для браузеров, и для не браузеров.

Comment: Если я пишу приложение без AJAX, то никто же мне не запрещает всё равно сделать API отдельно от основного сайта. Верно и обратное: если я пишу приложение (почти) целиком на AJAX, то никто не запрещает мне гонять обыкновенный HTML-код без каких-либо намёков на нормальное API)

Comment: @andreymal Вы что, тупой? Причем здесь "запрещает", здесь вопрос затрат времени, делать отдельно - дольше, чем все вместе. На этом разговор окончен, если до сих пор не поняли, то это ваши проблемы.

Comment: Нет, делать одинаково. Если нужно API, то случае обычного сайта делается API плюс рендеринг HTML на сервере (PHP, Smarty, Django, Jinja2, erb и т.п.), в случае SPA делается API плюс рендеринг HTML в браузере (React, Angular, что там ещё нынче модно) — разницы по скорости не вижу, API делать одинаково в любом случае, время на HTML тоже тратить в любом случае. Если вы этого не понимаете, но нам придётся обмениваться взаимными оскорблениями)

Comment: "случае обычного сайта делается API плюс рендеринг HTML на сервере" Это не API. Для него очень неудобно писать мобильные приложения, поскольку оно возвращает HTML, а не JSON. Я и не такое понимаю, и сервера пишу и мобильные приложения и паяльником тоже "программирую", меня стоит слушать хотя бы за это, а вот вы - тупой нуб.

Comment: То есть случай, когда сервер может возвращать как HTML, так и JSON, вы даже не рассматриваете? Так делает, например, ВК, и, думаю, там заявили бы, что это вы тупой нуб :) Видимо, дальнейший разговор действительно бессмысленнен, так как у вас очень ограниченный кругозор в плане веба. Развивайтесь.

Comment: @andreymal Но ведь реализовать возврат и того, и другого, - уйдет гораздо больше времени, чем только одного, или вы и с этим будете спорить? Насчет того, кто бы что заявил - уясните, что нет единственно-правильного решения, и я не говорил, что JSON API таковым является. Если мобильного приложения вообще пока не планируется, то я сам против JSON. Кругозор у меня не узкий, а феноменально широкий, в том числе и в Web, я боты для сайтов пишу и видел десятки разных API, включая VK, который я не мог не заметить. Но, именно поэтому я осознаю разнообразие задач, и плюсы и минусы как JSON, так и HTML.

Comment: Нет, не больше. [Отвечу в чате.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56445/discussion-between-andreymal-and-rou1997)

Answer (score 1):

Смотря на каком фрейморке сделан сайт. К примеру, Google умеет индексировать сайты на Angular, а вот Яндекс их "не видит". Поэтому для SEO рекомендуется делать html-версию сайтов для роботов.

Наиболее простым способом генерации HTML-версии сайта является использование headless-браузера для ренгеринга страниц, например, PhantomJS. Можно делать это на лету или же отдавать кэшированные заранее страницы.